# Update Xcode from 4.6.1 to 4.6.3 for Homebrew

Tags: mac-appstore, command-line, xcode, software-update

I have installed Xode downloading the DMG (not from the Mac App Store). Now each time I run `brew doctor` it says:

```
Your Xcode (4.6.1) is outdated
Please install Xcode 4.6.3.
```

But In App Store > Available Updates.. it does not appear. How can I upgrade it?

Please note that I'm not using Xcode but Xcode command-line tools (the C++ compiler) and if possible I would like to avoid reinstalling it.

Comment: Since you didn't install Xcode from the Mac App Store it won't display updates for it. You need to download the newest version from https://developer.apple.com and update manually. You may prefer to uninstall Xcode instead and purchase the App Store version (which is free). Once it is installed go to Xcode>Preferences>Downloads>Components to download the command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found [this](https://gist.github.com/myobie/1860902) on GitHub Gists.

Try enter the following command in Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Solved my `brew doctor` problem of Homebrew not recognising updated version of Xcode.

Also see [this](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Xcode) Homebrew compatibility guide and ensure that your OS is compatible with Command Line Tools on their own or if you need the full version of Xcode.